# Error running builder 'GWT Project Validator'

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Trying to import UniTime Project from Github. When building the project GWT Validator keeps showing error. I tried almost all GWT SDKs but problem still not solved.

Errors occurred during the build.
  Errors running builder 'GWT Project Validator' on project 'UniTime'.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computePackageFragmentRoots([Lorg/e  clipse/jdt/core/IClasspathEntry;ZLjava/util/Map;)[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/IPackageFragmentRoot;

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

GWT - 2.8.2

[GWT Project validator error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzgC9.png)

Comment: May be ralated to https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/365. What versions of the Eclipse and GWT Plugin do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I've edited my question and added the versions of the Eclipse(Oxygen. 1a Release(4.7.1a) and GWT-2.8.2 and posted a pic of the error am getting.

Comment: Oh and This http://help.unitime.org/eclipse was the link i was following to import the project and i wasn't able to execute the 4.C) instruction.

Comment: Check that you are using the latest version of the GWT Eclipse Plugin. It should be `3.0.0.201710201907` or higher.